# What type of pattern should I use for my passwords?

Tags: passwords, password-management

I have a lot of accounts and until some time ago I used an universal password for all of them. Right now I have a different password for every account depending on the website name that I am logging in. I use a pattern and the difference between patterns is the website domain name.

I dont want to store my password in some kind of password manager. I just want to have a pattern in mind and compose the password depending of it (and a piece of paper hidden somewhere safe in the house in case I am really dumb and I forget the pattern).

1. Could you suggest me some good patterns? So I can get one or a mix of them to make a better pattern for my passwords.
2. Is there any better way to store passwords but still access them if you need to log from another computer/device?(I dont really trust password managers)

Comment: *What specifically* about password managers do you not trust? If you clarify that, we might be able to either ease your concern *or* suggest an approach that means the particular issue is not a significant concern.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I dont know how are the password managers made. That's why I dont trust them. But right now I am reading about them and maybe I will choose one.

Comment: I wish there was an answer that wasn't so draconian.  I have maybe 5 accounts anywhere that I actually care about and I've memorized their unique passwords.  I have about 5000 random accounts that I have the username for (in my email history), but can't remember the password so I just reset it every time.  Then, I have about 50 accounts that I use occasionally.  It would be extremely convenient to know a "formula" for those sites.  [I just want to run faster than the other guy when being chased by a bear.](http://bit.ly/1Oaeg4l)

Comment: Cristi, consider that password managers are written *specifically* to manage passwords in a secure fashion. It's a purpose-made tool for a very specific job. This actually greatly *reduces* complexity, which in turn lowers the probability of an error creeping in. (Sure it can still happen, but it becomes less likely the less the software aims to do.)

Comment: Wasn't there an article somewhere about someone who basically memorized a hashing scheme + salt and then just used the website domain + the salt as his password on each service? Can't find the article now, but it does sound very similar to what you want. I do recall it taking a **lot** of memorization though.

Comment: Sometimes it's not about trust, but policy. The majority of passwords I have to remember are for work use, banking and finance, and government sites. These all (a) have policies against storing passwords that range from limited liability in cases of fraud to simply getting fired, and (b) have the most ridiculous rules about frequency of change, content and pattern (making them hardest to remember). So sometimes, password managers are out of the question and a pattern is the only way.

Comment: Someone I know has all her passwords handwritten in a diary.

Comment: If you're worried about how it's made, grab the source for PasswordSafe or another open-source manager and make it yourself.

Comment: @detly You can't create a good rule for a bad system. If the regulation you have to follow is bad (in the way you described it), you cannot "fix" it by using a "good" pattern.

Comment: There is absolutely *NO* pattern that your brain can think of and remember effectively while also simultaneously being good, strong passwords which resist all of today's modern password crackers.

Comment: KeePass is open source and free. http://keepass.info/download.html

Comment: @detly Wait, you can't store the passwords even in a proper password manager, but they also have to be impossible to memorize, and there has to be a lot of them?

Comment: @BlacklightShining ...is it news to anyone that corporate/financial password policies are stupid?

Comment: @Stephane Right, which means you can't "fix" it by using a password manager either.

Comment: Excuse my frustration, but it seems to be a common pattern on this site to insist on disregarding policies people think are bad, when it really is something that huge numbers of people need to negotiate. I'd argue that these policies, not poor technical proficiency, are at the root of a great deal of security issues. It would be nice if people could bring themselves to help others use "bad" systems in *better* ways, even if it isn't perfect. (I guarantee that most anyone reading this is subject to at least one such policy themselves, and has crossed it somehow.)

Comment: Not sure what the problem is with a string of 20 uniformly random hexadecimal characters. Short and sweet. It's easier to remember than it looks, I promise; you are not a monkey, you CAN remember it, even several of them if need be (so you can use one for your password manager and then a few others on the side etc). In exchange you get a nice password with 80 bits of entropy (no more, no less) that is completely safe from all offline-based brute force or dictionary attacks in the foreseeable future. The End. No need to waltz around with moronic password policies.

Comment: @detly I appreciate your point of view but, unfortunately, I can't for two reasons: 1/ Attempting to "fix" such a system only makes it look more solid 2/ the responsibility for fixing it doesn't lie on the user asking for a martingale but on the people setting the policies. If the end users try to fix it, they actually run the risk of going against these policy makers.

Comment: @detly if you use a password manager that properly secures the password this will never increase your liability because it is the appropriate and reasonable thing to do. It is impossible to memorize more than a handful of passwords that are not reused, change regularly and are not written down, any policy that requires you to do so is both unrealistic and unreasonable and will be deemed so if tested in any legal case.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

**None**. Use a password manager application to generate long, random password for each site.

Make sure you are not using your master password (or a derivation of your master  password) anywhere else.

If you do not trust online or commercial password managers, then use one that is open source and works with local files.

**Edit**: For reference, Bruce Schneier has published in 2014 a rather complete (and very readable) [blog post](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2014/03/choosing_secure_1.html) as to why using any kind of pattern for generating passwords is a bad idea.

Comment: Do you trust online or commercial password managers?

Comment: Define trust... but that's very subjective and is much like trust in any other commercial arrangement. If you really care, write your own or find an open source one you can analyse before using, but like in any industry there are a number of generally trusted providers.

Comment: That blog post is still somewhat controversial. Schneier ignores the equivalence of the relationship between word and dictionary and between character and alphabet. Consider each character or word as a number up to the limit contained in either alphabet or dictionary, then form a password as a sequence of these numbers. Weak passwords simply choose too few elements from too small a set (or common subset).

Comment: Isn't `a long, random password` just another pattern?

Comment: @ott - No. Its a long random password. Random = no pattern.

Comment: @Cristi I trust popular open source password managers.  Why?  Because I know there are people who are *far* more paranoid than me and have *far* more free time to be paranoid with scouring the code, ready to scream "Illuminati" or "Three Letter Agency" the instant they find something.  I trust that the paranoia of others is greater than my need for security for my Ashley Madison account.  -- wait, did I say that in a public channel?  Nevermind me! Hey, look! The Illumnati are taking over the government \*vanishes\*  *(If a password was very valuable, I would not trust anything, even my PC)*

Comment: I'm unconvinced what the blog post says about the XCKD post - as the post *assumes* the hacker knows your pattern, and it's still more secure.

Comment: @CortAmmon: I used to think that way about open source.  Then Heartbleed happened.

Comment: @Tim: The problem with the xkcd scheme is one of scale.  It assumes we are not worrying about cracking a stolen hash, which is problematic in this brave new world of one-big-company-gets-hacked-every-week.  This can be fixed by using more than four words (though how many more is not immediately obvious to me).

Comment: @Kevin Each word adds 11 bits of entropy according to the XKCD calculation. This should increase the cracking time by ~2000 times, no matter what technique is used.

Comment: @Kevin True, though I still hold that Heartbleed didn't hurt me enough to warrant out paranoia-ing the paranoid.  That's tough work.  Those guys are good at it!  (I was actually more disturbed by the MySQL buffer overflow that was actually caught properly in the code, but the compiler was optimizing the check away!)

Comment: @CortAmmon: They are good at it when they are looking at all, which in the case of OpenSSL, they basically weren't.  In an ideal world, you would audit every piece of code you rely on in any way.  Of course, that would be prohibitively expensive, so you compromise and only audit the x% most likely to cause problems.  But I  still think it's important to be aware of those tradeoffs so you're not caught flat-footed when something like Heartbleed happens.

Comment: @Kevin Fair enough lesson to learn.  Of course, that doens't mean I'm going to make my own tin foil hats.  The guys down the street in the VW make them far better than I could.

Comment: Bruce's recommendation is odd.He eschews passphrases, but supports abbreviated passphrases.

Comment: @PaulDraper What's odd about it ? A "real" word has less entropy than a (well) abbreviated one because it comes from a potentially smaller list.

Comment: So, using a password manager, how do I log into a library web service using a computer in the library? I don't trust the computer with anything other than my library web service account.

Comment: @JiK: There are password managers for smartphones, so that you'll only have to enter your library webservice password into the library computer, nothing else. (Next problem: can I trust my smartphone's OS provider?)

Comment: @JiK If you do not trust the system, do not use it to log into your account. In addition, in some cases, you can use a device like [InputStick](http://inputstick.com/index.php/en/). I'm using that for physically logging on servers in our DC (machines that I trust but but that don't have access to my PW manager)

Comment: @Stephane Isn't bluetooth hopelessly insecure? Just type it.

Comment: Commercial vs open-source is a contentious issue, but any online PM that lets you reset your master password is one that has access to all your passwords and can share them with attackers.

Comment: I wouldn't say "hopelessly insecure", but, in the case of InpuStick, you can add AES encryption on the communication between the USB device and the smartphone: that makes it quite secure.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky Not necessarily: there are scheme that allows the master password to be changed without requiring it to be shared. That doesn't mean you don't have to put some trust in the service, mind you. it's really a choice of convenience vs. security.

Comment: @Stephane How is that possible? And do you specifically mean "without requiring the master password to be shared" or more generally "without letting the password keeper read your passwords at whim."

Comment: @MarchHo yes, and that's a set of 2048 words - you could make that significantly larger and it would still be fairly memorable.

Comment: @Stephane: Schneier's argument isn't just about entropy. If one can quantify the amount of entropy that "Schneier abbreviation" adds to the phrase, then the scheme has the same entropy as using the phrase unabbreviated and sticking the equivalent number of randomly-generated characters on the end. But he's not just interested in entropy (and in any case the whole problem is that humans aren't very good at remembering enough entropy for N passwords). He is interested specifically in generating passphrases that defeat known guessing algorithms, and therefore out-perform their formal entropy.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer - No, "next problem" is what happens when I drop that phone in the toilet and can no longer access the password manager data?

Comment: @T.E.D., you have the password database synced on the cloud (since it's encrypted, it doesn't make any difference)

Comment: @SteveJessop I don't understand how a password can out-perform its formal entropy. A 10-character-password (upper/lower case and digits) created from an abbreviated sentence has ca. 60 bits entropy. Let's assume this schema really gives completely random passwords. The cracker needs to try (2^60)/2 passwords on average, cause it's completely random. A completely random Diceware phrase of 5 words has 8192^5 ie. 65 bits entropy, so the attacker needs to try (2^65)/2 word combinations. What shortcuts could an attacker take to reduce this amount of combinations?

Comment: @oliver: if a password is generated with less than 40 bits of entropy, but doesn't actually appear in the first trillion passwords tried by any real-world password cracker then (according to the model Schneier is using), it out-performs what you'd expect based on entropy alone. Schneier's claim for "Schneier abbreviation" is that password crackers are less good at solving an abbreviation with entropy N, than they would be at solving "passphrase plus random wart" with some entropy greater than N. Unfortunately he doesn't actually say *how much* greater, or what entropy he'd consider adequate.

Comment: So for example, the very earliest version of Schneier's advice of this kind that I remember, many years ago, is that it's better to put a random plug in the middle of a memorable sentence than at the end of one, because he observed that crackers at that time were trying dictionary words and phrases with junk appended, but not with junk inserted. The entropy is the same either way (well, plus or minus a handful of bits for the choice of insertion point), but at that time the inserted junk substantially out-performed the appended junk.

Comment: ... of course, if you can memorise a 65 bit random password then you might as well do so. Passphrases, and how to jigger them to make them resistant against crackers, are a game for people who've tried that and failed given the number of distinct passwords they need to know.

Comment: @Tim regarding Bruce and XKCD: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62832/is-the-oft-cited-xkcd-scheme-no-longer-good-advice

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky I can't tell you  specifics ATM but i gather that last pass hash the password to secure this. I can't remember if they let you recover it or not..

Answer (score 40):

If you don't trust password managers, you don't have to store the entire password in the password manager.

You can **split your password** into an easy to remember part that you remember (this could be the same for all websites if you wanted) and a unique long and random password in the password manager.

If somehow someone was able to access your password manager, they will still not have the part of the password that you remember in your head.

Comment: "easy to remember part that you remember" -- or even a quite hard-to-remember part, that you put some effort into memorising. Since it's the same for all your passwords, you only have to remember one thing (plus one more thing: the password manager's password) and you use it every day. 10-20 random characters isn't necessarily "easy to remember", but for passwords I use every day I can manage it, and as a very safe lower bound requires >2^50 guesses to crack by brute force.

Comment: Well, "easier to rememeber" is relative.  It will be easier than the very long random letters/numbers/symbols part that you will store in the password manager, but given that you now only have two passwords to remember (one for the password manager, and one you resuse and add to the password from the password manager), it could be "harder to remember" than if you had to remember a lot of passwords without using a password manager.

Comment: Please keep in mind that (too) many sites are restricting the number of characters in your password and/or the set of characters to choose from (frightening examples can be seen [here](http://passwordshaming.tumblr.com/). This might conflict with the proposed scheme: You either have to choose a very short and/or simple common part or probably deviate from your scheme (and have the complete password for certain sites saved in the manager software).

Comment: This is inconvenient though. Every time you have to login to a website, you have to look at the password manager, copy the part, and append your part, and *then* login. That's so much work.

Comment: A disadvantage of this would be that if a password leaked, because someone stored it in plain text, the remembered part is compromised.. (Which is a problem if the random part was shortened to allow the remembered part to be appended, due to length restrictions, etc...)

Comment: @GertvandenBerg, but how would they know that you are using a scheme that splits the password?

Comment: @JonnyWizz: Hack two sites and notice the matching parts? (unlikely with automated cracking though...) The security should not be based purely on the assumption that attackers don't know how the system works... (Which doesn't mean that it doesn't work while very few people are doing it that way...)

Comment: Well, in the unlikely event that the remembered part is compromised in this way, the rest of the passwords in the password manager will still be secure as the attacker only knows the remembered part.

Comment: I suppose there's one real risk, which is that if you don't trust the password manager then you probably shouldn't assume that it isn't logging your keystrokes to capture the remembered part. Fundamentally you can't install untrusted software on the same device you use to log into your accounts (for certain values of "same device": you might be willing to do something with virtualisation or even just with user accounts to ensure that the untrusted software is on the same device but without the ability to log).

Answer (score 9):

Random generation is the only pattern you want -- you can even [use dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diceware) (Wikipedia), or [for shorter random strings of letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_password_generator#Mechanical_methods) (Wikipedia again).

If you don't want to forget them, and don't trust a password manager [*write them down*!](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/06/write_down_your.html) (Schneier.com). I would consider some form of obfuscation here so that a casual thief stealing your wallet can't just log in to your paypal account (for example), even though this is hard to do well.

Comment: By simple obfuscation, you can simply "shift" the passwords down 2 or 3, so that you see the wrong password next to the username e.g. http://paste.ubuntu.com/13005200/

Comment: @Tim, that would work, other ideas might be swapping the case of letters (perhaps only in a subset of the password) if a random alphanumeric string is used.

Comment: Yeah, another good one. I personally am careful about changing the password itself - like writing it backwards because I find myself forgetting occasionally... I have a password manager in reality.

Comment: @Tim me too (or rather I'm fighting with KeePass2/KeeFox on linux)

Comment: @Tim Though trying each password in the database with each account in the database would probably be the first thing an attacker would try. That or just using the database as a wordlist against stolen hashes.

Comment: @Blacklight the premise of this obfuscation is that we're staying from a handwritten list, so the thief (or his buddy who "knows computers") would have to type them all in to a file and write a script, assuming more than a handful of passwords of course.

Answer (score 7):

1) If you don't trust online password managers, you can use offline managers like keepass2, but you'll have to get your file accessible anywere and the breach would be there. If you really don't want to trust password managers... learn your passwords.

2) There are several types of pattern which can be used to generate passwords. They are not always safe, so generated one are better. An article has been publicated on this subject on NakedSecurity [here](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2015/10/24/do-you-find-passwords-too-darn-hard-then-poetrys-your-hidden-card/?utm_source=Naked%2520Security%2520-%2520Feed&utm_medium=feed&utm_content=rss2&utm_campaign=Feed), they present different possible patterns.

Comment: The accessibility of the password file does not matter. It can be completely public, because it is encrypted. The weak link is trusting the computer on which *you enter the master password to decrypt it.*

Answer (score 7):

I would like to refer you to [this XKCD](https://xkcd.com/936/):

[image]

If you add e.g. a site name to the end of a password like that (and please don't use "correcthorsebatterystaple" now), it would be very secure.

What really matters is the length. So, if it's long and easy to remember, that is perfect.

A suggestion if you have trouble with password managers: store the password manager file on something like Dropbox. That way you can access it from anywhere, and it's still safe.

Comment: Patterns can weaken your passwords in (at least) two different ways: the worst patterns make your individual passwords easier to crack, whereas an identifiable pattern (simple or otherwise) will make subsequent passwords easier to crack after the first. This strategy avoids falling into the first trap, but unless you also change the 4-word base, falls victim to the second. Assume at least one of your passwords on a minor site has been cracked already - "correcthorsebatterystaplebank" may be secure, but what if the hacker already has "correcthorsebatterystaplestackexchange"?

Comment: Well as safe as Dropbox is...

Comment: @Tim It doesn't matter how safe Dropbox is since it's a password manager encrypted file.

Comment: @Tomas As the number of opening attempts is not limited, the safety of DropBox can matter. A person who has access to your dropbox has access to your encrypted file. He can then try a bruteforce attack on the master password. It doesn't represent a great risk if the master password is very long and complex, but still a risk.

Comment: @Zrechim Well, that's why we try to minimise the risks by using good passwords in the first place – including for the password manager of course. The risk with a good 25 character password is quite minimal.

Comment: 44 bits of entropy is too low. Passwords aren't cracked at 1000 guesses/sec, they're sometimes cracked at a trillion guesses/sec, which will crack the password in 16 seconds.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky please don't exagerate, I assume you are from the USA or UK where trillion means 1,000,000,000,000. This means that even should password hashing only take 1 operation this would need a 1THz processing capability. Assuming most non state-funded cracking is done by bot-nets this would equate to 200 bot 2-core CPU's running at 2.5 GHz (averages from Steam hardware survey). Not impossible but it is costly. But this was assuming 1 instruction per hash, it gets extremely costly when using for example BCrypt with 2^12 rounds which seems to be used a lot. But sure, more is better.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky Well, toss in a few numbers in the mix and it pops to 36²⁵, which would take *a little* more than 16 seconds to crack. As in, forever.

Comment: If you use IncorrectcowcapacitornailWEBSITE your password will be *totes* safe.

Comment: @Selenog Your hardware knowledge is lacking. A GPU can do 8,000 operations per clock cycle, but that's beside the point. Typical hashes are cracked at hundreds of billions attempts per second. ASICs can do orders of magnitude better--bitcoin rigs can do [8 trillion SHA1 hashes per second](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_Hardware_Comparison) on much less electricity. Nation states have surely built similar ASICs for password cracking. You're right that bcrypt or at least using multiple rounds is much better. I did use the word "sometimes." But today, fast/weak hashing is used quite often.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky Who said it had to be SHA1? Is there even a single offline password manager that uses that for its encryption key? I doubt it.

Comment: @Tomas 36^25 applies to 25 random alphanumeric characters. A 25-character passphrase is not a set of random characters. It has far less entropy. Don't kid yourself here. Even a hacker who hasn't read your post here knows there's, let's say, a 10% chance you went with the "pick four words and toss in a few numbers" strategy, so you can add at most 3 bits of entropy to account for him not knowing your strategy with certainty.

Comment: @Tomas Password managers do usually use a fast hash like SHA1, but use it in multiple rounds which adds 10-20 bits of entropy. However, if you use such a passphrase (plus website name) on every site (as the OP intended), and one of those sites uses single-round SHA1 (which plenty will), then that's your weakest link.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky *A 25-character passphrase is not a set of random characters. It has far less entropy.*
How do you know that?
There is a difference between the passwords stored *in* the password manager and the password used to *lock* the password manager.
So, do you have a real point here or are you just trying to "win" the discussion?

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky *Password managers do usually use a fast hash like SHA1* How do you know that? KeePass, for example, uses AES.

Comment: @Tomas AES is used for encryption. AES uses an encryption key that *is not* your password. This key is derived from your password by a hashing function. As stated here in the [key derivation section](http://keepass.info/help/base/security.html) this hashing function is SHA-256, plus N rounds of AES with a public key (ok, so it does use AES for key derivation). N equals 6000 by default. Neither is SHA1, but both SHA2 and AES are fast *like* SHA1. KeePass doesn't use bcrypt or scrypt.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky Let me give you a hint: [How difficult to crack keepass master password?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8476/how-difficult-to-crack-keepass-master-password).

Comment: @Tomas for KeePass in particular, I found [one program](http://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329220/thread/ab72879e). It only does 1000 guesses/s, but it's written in C#. If it can be efficiently rewritten for a GPU, I'd expect at least 1,000,000. That's about 3 months for 44 bits. Not instant, but too close for comfort.

Comment: @Tomas The asker in that question proposed using a 66 bit password (ie, one that is 4,000,000 times more complex than yours) and the answerer hadn't heard of a GPU. Don't use phrases like "let me give you a hint." You're being rude.

Comment: @Aleksandr Dubinsky hash functions used for passwords should be with for example multiple rounds as to make them inefficient on GPU's. This because servers tend not to have GPU's so why give attackers an edge. There are other ways to make them inefficient on GPU's ofc.

Comment: @Selenog Using multiple rounds does not affect GPU efficiency. Hashing functions which are inefficient on GPUs use additional memory. However, using a low-memory, fast hashing function many times does not pose a problem for a GPU. The GPU slows down by a factor of N just as a CPU, but maintains its large lead.

Comment: @Aleksandr Dubinsky I believe it does, a GPU is good at simultaneous execution but due to lower clockspeed is bad at sequential execution. A CPU has the inverse properties ofc. But that was just one example, add in for example some branching (GPU's have no or lacking branching prediction) and  it gets less and less attractive to use a GPU, you still can but won't get the factor 1000 and the like you see with GPU minded hashes. However it is a fair point to bring up GPU's as you are right that a lot of sites use poorly chosen hash functions.

Comment: In practice, passphrases don't seem to help as much as XKCD would have you believe:  https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2335356.2335366

Answer (score 6):

You can use a hash-based password generation strategy. You combine a master password with the site name (and its complexity requirements) to generate a password unique to the site.

It has some advantages and disadvantages compared to a password manager:

- There is no encrypted database that you can lose / get stolen and attacked
- You need to remember the settings used to make the approach work for sites with different complexity requirements
- A poor implementation, like taking 8 characters from a md5 hash can reduce the keyspace significantly.
- Cases where you are forced to change your password are hard to handle

There are a few tools that can be used:

- normal hashing functions (You should avoid this) e.g. The [example presented here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55592/password-managers-encrypted-database-vs-hashing-strategy) (That post also have the strengths and weaknesses of the approach)
- Tools to automate the process, like [supergenpass](http://www.supergenpass.com/) (MD5 based by default which is not ideal, a slower hash makes recovering you master password trickier if a generated password + the sitename is known to an attacker) (Although you should probably have a master password that is long and random enough that it is hard to brute-force) (Other exist, such as Master Password, see below)

(Via Matty: [Master Password](http://masterpasswordapp.com/algorithm.html) seems to use a much better way to generate passwords than any of the others mention previously)

Comment: Some of the other examples include http://plevyak.com/dpg.html (Likely based on a better hash, but something intentionally slow like bcrypt, PBKDF2 or scrypt would still have its advantages)

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Its big advantage is you don't need to keep track of a file (and worry about losing it). However, it's not more secure. If, previously, an attacker would need to get hold of the file to start cracking, now he only needs to get hold of one of your passwords.

Comment: For the sites where they keep making you pick a new password (hence, site name), you can write it down in a plaintext file or notebook. The strategy will still work (if the master password is sufficiently secure).

Comment: Oh, also you're not wedded to a single app, since there's no file format to worry about. Hash generators are available even as Javascript pages.

Comment: This is the strategy that is used in the 'passwordmanager' http://masterpasswordapp.com/. Changing passwords there is easy, they just use a number next to the master password and the site name that you increase every time you need to change your password.

Comment: @Matty: That seems to be a really good one to start with... (On counters: You still need to keep track of them...)

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky: It gets rid of many of the weaknesses of password managers, except for the master password, but introduces some new ones instead. (The real problem is that we need to keep track of hundreds of passwords in the first place, which is harder to solve, OpenID made it somewhat better - I can log in here using my Facebook account, but it is still a problem)

Comment: I realized the gotcha. You can't change the master password (without changing all the passwords).

Answer (score 6):

Use a [Password Card](http://www.passwordcard.org/en).
Here is one example:
[image]
With a password card, you pick a starting point and a path for where to go from there (up, down, left, right, diagonals, or some combination) and remember that.  (Or, multiple starting points and paths per password.)  You don't have to trust software password managers because the paper card is your password manager, and the hash at the bottom is the "master password."  You still have to keep track of some information (starting point and path) separate from the manager, so even if you lose your wallet the passwords aren't gone with it.

Comment: from their website, "Enjoy your new feeling of safety and peace of mind... :-)".  Sounds like the definition of [security theater](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/173943/149193).

Answer (score 3):

I think "Off The Grid" (https://www.grc.com/offthegrid.htm) might meet your requirements. It's based on a randomly generated grid and a method based on the domain name to generate the password from that. The pages on that site describe the "standard" way of using the grid, but there are also suggestions about how you could tweak it, so even if someone got hold of your grid and knew the "standard" method, they still wouldn't be able to work out your passwords.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use popular quotes from movies. I take the first letter of each word and turn each into a different capital letter, lower case letter, symbol or number and try to use 4 of each and keep them different.

> 'What' ain't no country I ever heard of, do they speak English in
>   'what'?

becomes "W@4c!3%7D^S9Iw?". I like to tag on a small series of symbols and letters I can remember if its too short. like 456 with shift held every other one. "W@4c!3%7D^S9Iw?$5^"

Comment: I can't imagine that this would be much better than using the quote itself. That wouldn't be so bad if you picked sentences at random from a collection of works, but since you're using _popular_ quotes…

Comment: It also doesn't solve the problem of remembering different passwords for different sites...

Comment: To me it was a bit like a memory palace. Instead of a associating a room with something to remember, I associate the movie and the quote with a server or website. It helped me remember longer and stronger passwords and what they were for.

Comment: I believe this technique is now in password crackers...

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is use a complex base string for the password like `AdasfbkSDUn7657AJDadadsag` and then for the website , which I am creating the password for, I would append it's name to the begining. If remembering the password seems daunting (which should be , use an ***offline*** password manager).

Example password for - `www.website.com`

```
web_AdasfbkSDUn7657AJDadadsag
```